How to create a dashboard template that uses a parameterized data source for multi-tenancy?
I have multiple customer databases (with identical schema) as part of a multi-tenant application. I would like to create a "template" of a dashboard (that contains several charts generated from the data in a customer database). The end goal is that each customer, when logging into their application, can see the embedded dashboard that uses their customer database.
I don't want to have to create the dashboard separately for each customer, but a sort of "template", and pass in a parameter that identifies which customer database to use. Ideally, I'd like to do this WITHOUT having to create a data-lake where I combine all the customer databases together to form one mega-dataset with a customer discriminator.
I've found articles discussing various multi-tenant strategies involving namespaces, groups, RLS/CLS, etc. But my big challenge is that the list of customer databases is dynamic. Customers (and their associated databases) are added and removed every day, so my solution needs to be able to handle that.
I would like the web frontend to be able to make an API call with it's tenant id, and then (perhaps with the help of an intermediate lambda), get an embeddable URL that contains the dashboard of that tenant that uses that tenant's database. In the "back office", I would create and regularly update a dashboard template (using the QuickSight UI) with various reports/charts using a sample customer database, and it would be reflected in all actual customer's embedded dashboard.
While typing this question, I discovered Quicksight: Changing data source for a dataset.

I'm not sure if this approach can help in your case  : a - create a dashboard template with the sample database. b - manage the customer databases with Glue, perhaps run Glue crawler at each time you add or remove database to update a data catalog. c - finally using Lambda to fetch database details based on tenantid parameter  and dynamically create QuickSight datasource and generate an the dashboard URL.

Are you separating the customers via namespaces?

I am not separating customers via namespaces at the moment, but am open to do so if necessary.

You've already answered your question..... AWS QuickSight.
Use /?tenantId=123 type filtering when loading the dashboard and you can use that to map between the different database hostnames or database schemas.
It's a really powerful tool.

How do I use a parameter to map between different database hostnames? This solution makes sense if they were all combined into one data lake, but not if they are distinct databases. Am I missing something here?

Just use the same concept. i.e. in simple terms ?databaseHostname=abc123 - Naturally you'd probably want to abstract that kind of detail for security reasons, but you just need some kind of lookup or whatever to determine this.
